# --proof=* Meaning shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell

First of all, i must say that i tried. really. But i'm stuck at this point for 3 days and i need to move on and finish it.

I've found no references in man. I've found No references in bash reference. I've found no references in the holy bible.
And it's kinda tricky google  it because just "proof bash" is too generic and --proof kills my own search...

The problem: I have a shell script and i have to analyze it and explain what he does and why (common exercise for whom is starting at bash programming).

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    set $PWD
fi
for ARG in $*
    do
    case $ARG in 
        --proof=*)
            PROFUNDIDADE=`echo $ARG | cut -f 2 -d '='`
            Bla bla bla
```

I wont post all the code because i dont want people think i want someone to do it for me. 
My problem is just the %%$#@$ "--proof=*)"

Does someone can clarify it? 
Thanks!

Comment: If the scripts is called with `thisscript.sh --proof=somevar`, set the variable `$PROFUNDIDADE` to that value after the first `=` (`somevar`).

Comment: That's a point. We have no information about how the script is called.
but shouldn't --proof be indexed by $- instead $*? As far as I know, $* is for positional arguments.

Comment: I have no idea about `$-`... But yes, you are looping through all positional arguments... _any_ argument is a positional argument. In my example, the first argument would be `"--proof=somevar"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help case`:

```
case: case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... esac
    Execute commands based on pattern matching.

    Selectively execute COMMANDS based upon WORD matching PATTERN.  The
    `|' is used to separate multiple patterns.
```

`PATTERN` in this case (and in most bash cases) can be read as "glob". It matches anything starting with "--proof=".

Comment: Thank you for answering. I feel a little stupid by now, i really look after a complex command and it was simply the normal case.